# use bulkDestroy in Sequelize

Tags: sql-delete, sequelize.js

I'd like to know how to delete all values in an array, my array contains the ids like: `[1,2,3,4]`, I've tried:

```
models.products
.destroy({where: {req.body.ids}})
.then(function(data){ res.json(data) })
```

But I got `data` undefined, and nothing is deleted...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've missed the `id` from your criteria.

```
Model.destroy({ where: { id: [1,2,3,4] }})
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to +Adam's response:

for arrays you'll need to add an $in: clause.

```
Models.products
 .destroy({where: {$in: req.body.ids}})
 ...
```

Comment: I think that should be `{where: {id: {$in: req.body.ids}}}`, per http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#operators